# How can i make my TCP server respond to more than one request per connection?

Tags: python, sockets

So i have a code for my tcp server. It gets a string, echoes it and closes the connection. What i want to do is that server will get more than one request and respond to more than one client and closes connection only if there is a mistake or client disconnected. How can i do this?

```
import threading
import socket

def run_server(port):
  serv_sock = create_serv_sock(port)
  cid = 0
  while True:
    client_sock = accept_client_conn(serv_sock, cid)
    t = threading.Thread(target=serve_client,
                         args=(client_sock, cid))
    t.start()
    cid += 1

def serve_client(client_sock, cid):
  request = read_request(client_sock)
  if request is None:
    print(f'Client #{cid} unexpectedly disconnected')
  else:
    response = handle_request(request)
    write_response(client_sock, response, cid)

def create_serv_sock(serv_port):
  serv_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM,proto=0)
  serv_sock.bind(('localhost', serv_port))
  serv_sock.listen()
  return serv_sock

def accept_client_conn(serv_sock, cid):
    client_sock, client_addr = serv_sock.accept()
    print(f'Client #{cid} connected '
          f'{client_addr[0]}:{client_addr[1]}')
    return client_sock

def read_request(client_sock, delimiter=b'!'):
  request = bytearray()
  while True:
    try:
      chunk = client_sock.recv(4)
      if not chunk:
        return None

      request += chunk
      if delimiter in request:
        return request

    except ConnectionResetError:
      return None
    except:
      raise

def handle_request(request):
  return request[::-1]

def write_response(client_sock, response, cid):
  client_sock.sendall(response)
  client_sock.close()
  print(f'Client #{cid} has been served')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_server(port = 9090)
```

i tried to make 2 independent funtions with `threading.Thread` like this

```
def response(message,client_sock):
    client_sock.sendall(f'you said: {message}')


def handle(client_sock):
    while True:
        try:
            request = client_sock.recv(1024)
            response(request,client_sock)
        except:
            client_sock.close()
            print ("client has disconected")
            break


def receive():
    while True:
        client_sock, client_addr = server_sock.accept()
        print(f"Connected with {client_addr[0]}:{client_addr[1]}")

        thread = threading.Thread(target = handle, args=(client_sock))
        thread.start()
```

But I always get a lot of thread errors

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with those attempts?

Comment: i tried to make 2 independent funtions with threading.Thread
like this
```def receive():
    while True:
        client_sock, client_addr = server_sock.accept()
        print(f"Connected with {client_addr[0]}:{client_addr[1]}")

        thread = threading.Thread(target = handle, args=(client_sock))
        thread.start()
```
But I always get a lot of thread errors

Comment: Please include that as an edit to your original question; comments do not format code very well.

Comment: Maybe fix the thread errors then. Maybe you should ask about the thread errors instead of asking about the socket.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Replace this function, I removed its While loop.

```
def read_request(client_sock, delimiter=b'!'):
  request = bytearray()
    try:
      chunk = client_sock.recv(4)
      if not chunk:
        return None

      request += chunk
      if delimiter in request:
        return request

    except ConnectionResetError:
      return None
    except:
      raise
```

2 - Replace this function, I moved the while loop here, which will keep running and checking for new messages and processing them

```
def serve_client(client_sock, cid):
    while True:
      request = read_request(client_sock)
      if request is None:
        print(f'Client #{cid} unexpectedly disconnected')
      else:
        response = handle_request(request)
        write_response(client_sock, response, cid)
```

3 - Replace this function, I removed the client_sock.close() as it would close the socket once you received one message, now the connection between client and server should stay on.

```
def write_response(client_sock, response, cid):
  client_sock.sendall(response)
  print(f'Client #{cid} has been served')
```

Comment: What does ```self``` mean?

Comment: I've got it inside a class, so ignore that. I'm gonna try to refactor your code, it's hard with servers because i don't really know what you trying to get from your Client.

Comment: I've edited my post again, replace those functions and see if they work. It should keep the connection going now.